# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for "topicna" -4: 96866 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for "topic_namexxxx" -4: 96866 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
Producer Fails to Publish Messages
```

tried increasing the batchsize and TimeOut

```
config
 Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "10485880"); //1048576(1MB)
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(524288)); //0.5MIB
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "100"); //100 ms
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "66554432"); //64MB
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "120000"); //120s
    props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "90000"); //90s
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, msg);

Scaling the Number of Containers have caused the change in concurrency could it be a reason

Comment: it shouldn't be related to the serialization, is this happening with all records, or after a while?, what is the sending rate?, did you tweak any of the producer configurations `batch.size`, `linger.ms`,`request.timeout.ms`?, share a snippet with how you send the message.

Comment: This happens because you are never flushing the producer... `send()` does not immediately make any network requests to the broker

Comment: I have updated my current config